# Is it possible to invoke a scope method in the ngTagsInput template?

Tags: angularjs, ng-tags-input

Something like

```
<script id="tagTemplate" type="text/ng-template">
    <div>
        <span>{{$getDisplayText()}}</span>
        <button ng-click='showDetails(data)'>More</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Comment: It looks like there is no direct hook to click events within the template. 

There is onTagClicked attribute for tagsInput directive which is invoked on click of each tag item. The clicked tag is passed as parameter to onTagClicked. onTagClicked can set be to showDetails(data). However this would mean not just clicking on "More" but clicking anywhere would invoke showDetails.

Comment: That's not currently possible, but I have already thought of implementing that feature. It might be a part of the next release.

Comment: @MichaelBenford, that would be really useful. Please put your comment as answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: @Bharat, yeah, I know about onTagClicked, but my problem was exactly the fact that it will be invoked by clicking anywhere on the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just got implemented and now it's possible to do `$scope.showDetails(data)`.